# Fastest way to return interpolated points within a meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have meshgrid points (X,Y,Z) and an array of points (xi,yi) in which I want to return the interpolated values zi.

The current approach would be:

```
from scipy import interpolate

ip = interpolate.interp2d(X, Y, Z); zi = ip(xi, yi)
```

However this process seems to be very slow for my dataset (xi,yi) size 1001

Is there a more efficient method?

[image: I have a]

Answer (score 2):

I found that the RectBivariateSpline function was significantly faster.

```
ip = RectBivariateSpline(xl, yl, Zhat.T)(x, y,grid=False)
```